# How can I append UInt8 (from an array) to a String?

Tags: swift

I need to read from a `UInt8` array and append certain bytes into a `String` but it gives me error no matter what I tried. `+=` doesn't work with `CChar(ptr[i])` it complains. `String.append()` doesn't work it expects `Character` and not `CChar`, and why in the hell everything is so convertible in Swift but not `CChar` to a `Character`? here's my sample func

```
func FromBuf(ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length len: Int) -> String {
  var i: Int = 0
  while (i < len) {
    if (i > 0) { s.append(CChar(ptr[i])) }
    i++
  }
  return s
}
```

Also, what would be the best way to set a `String` from a portion of a `UInt8` array? I tried this but it doesn't work, `var s = String(bytes: &ptr[3], encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)`. Actually this initialiser also lacks the way to specify how many bytes to get from the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Foundation method `NSString(bytes:length:encoding:)` to convert from raw bytes to a String.

```
import Foundation

func FromBuf(ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length len: Int) -> String? {
    // convert the bytes using the UTF8 encoding
    if let theString = NSString(bytes: ptr, length: len, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return theString as String
    } else {
        return nil // the bytes aren't valid UTF8
    }
}
```

If you just want to use a portion of the byte array, then you could also supply the starting offset to the function as an additional parameter.

```
import Foundation

func FromBuf(ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, startingOffset: Int, length len: Int) -> String? {
    // convert the bytes using the UTF8 encoding
    if let theString = NSString(bytes: ptr + startingOffset, length: len, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return theString as String
    } else {
        return nil // the bytes aren't valid UTF8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc, this even saved me from the append one char at a time thing